# Org Chart SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a table to hold an org chart using SQL Server but have not been successful so far. I have tried doing sub-selects and self-joins but I can't get the desired output.

This is what the table looks like today, showing who reports to who:

```
1    2         3
Bob  Jon     Kevin
Bob  Mark    Paul
Bob  Jon     Ian
```

My desired outcome is to show all resources in one column, and then display the org chart to the right, like this:

```
Resource    3        2       1
Kevin      Kevin    Jon     Bob
Paul       Paul     Mark    Bob
Ian        Ian      Jon     Bob
Jon        NULL     Jon     Bob
Mark       NULL     Mark    Bob
Bob        NULL     NULL    Bob
```

I am not sure if this is possible with SQL or what strategies I should use to accomplish it. Pivots, CTEs, etc.

Comment: How have you made sure that 2 employees can not have same name..like Bob reporting to Jon and Jon to Bob.. i mean is nesting there? 1.Bob 2.Jon 3.Bob

Comment: The underlying data set only contains two columns, one for the employee id and another for the manager id. I was able to build the first table by joining the table to itself 3 times looking for matches that allowed for the hierarchy. When employee id was not null but manager was, that meant the employee was the CEO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `apply` to unpivot and then use `select distinct` to remove duplicates:

```
select distinct v.*
from t cross apply
     (values (col3, col3, col2, col1),
             (col2, col2, col1, null),
             (col1, col1, null, null)
     ) v(resource, col3, col2, col1);
```

Comment: Gordon, thank you for the suggestion. Would this solution be able to build the table dynamically figuring out where the NULLS should be placed? For example, if I need to store a new employee and he is a level 2, than the level 3 should be NULL automatically. Thank you

Comment: @530529 . . . This does place the `NULL`s where are they are supposed to go, I think.